# filter at with multiple specific conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

My data frame follows the below structure. There is a column A which has related columns A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 and similarly for B.

```
# create dummy data frame
dummy_df=data.frame('ID'=c(1,2,3,4),'A'=c('false','false','true','false'),'A_1'=c('false','false','true','false'),'A_2'=c('true','false','false','false'),
                    'A_3'=c('false','false','true','false'),'A_4'=c('false','false','false','false'),'B'=c('false','true','false','false'),'B_1'=c('false','false','false','false'),'B_2'=c('false','true','false','false'),
                    'B_3'=c('false','false','true','false'),'B_4'=c('false','false','false','false') )
```

[image]

Checks that i intend to do are as follows :

1) Are there any rows where if A was = false , any of the sub heads (A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 ) was true e.g. ID 1 (A =false, A_2=true) below. For this i have come to the following code after researching online

```
  dummy_df %>% select(matches('ID|A|A_')) %>% filter(A=='false') %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 'true'))
```

Same check has to be done across the whole data frame with A and sub columns, B and its sub columns etc. I couldn't generalise the above into a function where i can just input the base column i want to check ( i.e. A or B) and lapply it on a list of base columns (A or B) returning df_A_mistmatch , df_B_mismatch(e.g. row ID 3) as outputs of the lapply function with their IDs in the frame.

2) Other output which helps to check the above is a cross tab with all sub columns i.e. to get the counts where A=false and A_1 or A_2 or A_3 or A_4 = true have counts>1

After looking through a lot of links i see that filter_at doesnt allow for anything else apart from `Any_vars` or `all_vars`and does not allow multiple conditions such as in this case - A=false and A_1 or A_2 or A_3 or A_4 = true. hence i used two filters below.

What are the optimal solutions for the problem above

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use logical values (TRUE/FALSE) instead of 'true'/'false' strings.

Try this to keep records that have "A = false and any of the sub heads (A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 ) = true"

```
library(dplyr)

dummy_df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-ID), function(x) x == 'true') %>% 
  filter(!A & rowSums(select(., starts_with("A_"))) > 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-ID), function(x) ifelse(x, 'true', 'false'))
```

PS. First `mutate` converts 'true'/'false' strings into logical T/F, and the last `mutate` converts back.

**Output**

```
#   ID     A   A_1  A_2   A_3   A_4     B   B_1   B_2   B_3   B_4
# 1  1 false false true false false false false false false false
```

Comment: Thanks @Nurandi. i was able to achieve a similar result as shared above but i am keen to get to a more generalized function which can be run via an apply on all base columns e.g. A , B above at once. End result to be a table with all such rows across any base column. Second output for similar check would be a cross tab across base and all its sub columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with `split.default` which will work for any number of groups -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dummy_df %>%
  select(-1) %>%
  split.default(sub('_.*', '', names(.))) %>%
  imap_dfc(~rowSums(.x[[.y]] == 'false' & .x %>% select(-.y) == 'true'))

#      A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0
#2     0     0
#3     0     1
#4     0     0
```

This reads as the first row in A group has 1 value which has `'true'` in any of the sub heads when `A` is `'false'` and same goes for group `B` in row 3.